# Simple Publisher Subscriber in Java

Tags: java, beginner, singleton, callback

I am new to Java and had some difficulty creating this simple Publisher Subscriber class. It finally seems to be working and I wanted to check if I have been following best practices and see if there are any improvements I can make.

The following Java class accepts any topics as a string (e.g. "rand_int") and forwards any messages to that topic to any subscribers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class PubSub {
  private Map<String, ArrayList<Consumer<?>>> topicsSubscribers =
      new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Consumer<?>>>();
  private static PubSub pubSubSingleton = null;

  public static PubSub getInstance() {
    if (pubSubSingleton == null)
      pubSubSingleton = new PubSub();

    return pubSubSingleton;
  }

  public <T> void publish(String topic, T message) {
    ArrayList<Consumer<?>> subscribers = this.topicsSubscribers.get(topic);
    if (subscribers == null)
      return;

    for (Consumer subscriberConsumer : subscribers) {
      subscriberConsumer.accept(message);
    }
  }

  public synchronized <T> void subscribe(String topicName, Consumer<T> subscriberCallback) {
    ArrayList<Consumer<?>> subscribers = this.topicsSubscribers.get(topicName);
    if (subscribers == null) {
      subscribers = new ArrayList<Consumer<?>>();
      subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
      this.topicsSubscribers.put(topicName, subscribers);
    } else {
      subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public SomeClass() {
    PubSub.getInstance().subscribe("rand_int", this::randIntCallback);
    PubSub.getInstance().publish("rand_int", 46);
  }

  public randIntCallback(int number) {
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

The above code should output "46".

As I said, I am very new to Java and would like some feedback on my code to help improve. So any help on this is very appreciated.

Comment: Your error message is off topic for this site.  If you pared it down to an MCVE, it would be on-topic on Stack Overflow.  But it would likely get closed as a duplicate of a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14524751/6660678).

Comment: Thanks mdfst13. Yes I only kept the error as the reason I wasn't able to improve my code a certain way. But I suppose you are right it's a bit off topic. Thanks for your answer as well. All very good points which I will look into and implement as much as possible.

Comment: You should give others some time to write an answer too before you accept the first answer you get.

Comment: @EmilyL. I originally was going to wait but figured if a better answer comes along I can just change the accepted answer. Is that not possible?

Comment: Sure but it discourages others from answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Initializing object variables

> ```
>   private Map<String, ArrayList<Consumer<?>>> topicsSubscribers =
>       new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Consumer<?>>>();
> ```

The standard is to set the types as the interfaces, like `Map` and `List`.

```
    private final Map<String, List<Consumer<?>>> topicSubscribers = new HashMap<>();
```

Also, you don't need to specify the contents of `<>` in the implementation instantiation.  The compiler will work that out for you.

#### Initializing class variables

> ```
>   private static PubSub pubSubSingleton = null;
>
>   public static PubSub getInstance() {
>     if (pubSubSingleton == null)
>       pubSubSingleton = new PubSub();
>
>     return pubSubSingleton;
>   }
> ```

You don't have to do it this way.  You can simply say

```
    private static final PubSub pubSubSingleton = new PubSub();

    public static PubSub getInstance() {
        return pubSubSingleton;
    }

    private PubSub() {
    }
```

This saves the null check each time while still only initializing once.

However, Singleton is generally considered an anti-pattern now.  You may want to consider [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1300655/6660678).  One possibility would be a separate instance for each message type.

Your original code does not make the constructor private.

The Java standard is four column indents rather than the two you are using.

#### Formatting

> ```
>     if (subscribers == null)
>       return;
> ```

If you are going to use the statement form, you should probably keep it one line:

```
    if (subscribers == null) return;
```

If it's too complicated to fit into one line, you should probably use the block form instead.

I actually use the block form consistently regardless.

```
    if (subscribers == null) {
        return;
    }
```

#### Factor out the common

> ```
>     if (subscribers == null) {
>       subscribers = new ArrayList<Consumer<?>>();
>       subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
>       this.topicsSubscribers.put(topicName, subscribers);
>     } else {
>       subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
>     }
> ```

This could be

```
    if (subscribers == null) {
        subscribers = new ArrayList<Consumer<?>>();
        topicsSubscribers.put(topicName, subscribers);
    }

    subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
```

You don't have to do the `add` before the `put`.  It's the same object either way.  Otherwise, you'd have to do the `put` after the `add` in the non-null case.

Answer (score 2):

We consider singletons bad (i.e. your `getInstance` bit). There are numerous resources on why a short search away so I'm not going to list them here.

That said your `getInstance` is not safe in a threaded context. You need to use [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). Note that I do think that initialising the object in the *static* constructor or inline with the declaration is safe as well.

Your `subscribe` method is `synchronized` on the class object but the `publish`  method is not meaning that you have a data race where the subscribers for a topic may change in the middle of iterating over it, typically this will throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) when it happens. Either you do a thread safe design and add `synchronized` to `publish` as well or do a thread-un-safe design and remove the `synchronized` keyword everywhere.

Your `publish` method swallows any errors. This is not good. Depending on your philosophy on error reporting you should either return a boolean signifying the success or failure of publishing the message to at least one receiver or throw an exception. In this case I would return an error, or maybe even the number of subscribers that the message was delivered too, yeah I think that makes more sense and is cheap to compute and rich in information.

And finally, your class will forever hold a reference to the subscriber object and is likely to cause a memory leak as you cannot remove them, especially since this is a singleton which has the same lifetime as your application. A common pattern is to either allow removal through `unsubscribe` or use [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and let the life time be tied to an external object with cleanup of any weak references whose get returns null (object removed/gcd)

Answer (score 2):

One small addition to what the others said:

```
ArrayList<Consumer<?>> subscribers = this.topicsSubscribers.get(topicName);
if (subscribers == null) {
  subscribers = new ArrayList<Consumer<?>>();
  subscribers.add(subscriberCallback);
  ...
```

is an outdated pattern. Since java 8 (i.e. 4.5 years now) we have `computeIfAbsent` in the Map. Therefore, use:

```
ArrayList<Consumer<?>> subscribers = this.topicsSubscribers.computeIfAbsent(sub -> new ArrayList<>());
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But wouldn't `putIfAbsent ()` be more appropriate here?

Comment: @KNejad No. For `putIfAbsent` you'd have to create a new list for every call which would be discarded in most cases. For `computeIfAbsent` you pass a supplier, which will only be called to create a new list if needed.